# Python - chown folder by username

Tags: python, chown

I'm trying create script for chown folder owner, but I have some problem with it.

I'm have are lot of folder in `/home`. For examle:

```
/home/user1
/home/user2
/home/user_n
```

And want to change owner for folder based on folder name. For folder `user1` need owner `user1`, for folder `user2` need owner `user2`, for `user_n` owner `user_n`.

Now I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

# Show only filders in /home
path = "/home/"
folderu = [f for f in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f))]
print folderu
```

This is print for me all folder names in `/home`.

I'm trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import pwd
import grp

# Show only filders in /home
path = "/home/"
folderu = [f for f in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f))]
print folderu

for somevar in folderu:
        uid = pwd.getpwnam(folderu).pw_uid
        gid = grp.getgrnam(folderu).gr_gid
        os.chown(folderu, uid, gid)
```

But this can't working.

Comment: You should probably use the full path in the argument to chown, i.e. intead of passing it `folderu`, instead pass `os.path.join(path, somevar)`

Comment: Maybe replace `uid = pwd.getpwnam(folderu).pw_uid` by `uid = pwd.getpwnam(somevar).pw_uid`?

Comment: oh wait - you should be using `somevar` in place of `folderu` as well

Comment: Thanks, all working fine. I just replace "folderu" to "somevar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import pwd
import grp

# Show only filders in /home
path = "/home/"
folderu = [f for f in os.listdir(path)
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f))]

for somevar in folderu:
    uid = pwd.getpwnam(somevar).pw_uid
    gid = grp.getgrnam(somevar).gr_gid
    os.chown(somevar, uid, gid)
```